# computation cost comparison between Boolean and arithmetic

Tags: python, computer-science

I have a general question regarding the computation cost of operations. Is the most basic Boolean operation cheaper or more expensive in time than the most basic arithmetic operation. In case there are edge cases then consider the stochastic case where you try out different inputs.

**UPDATE**
Just to refine the question slightly, I want to compare the time complexity of addition with the Boolean equals operations. Here is a resource for time complexity:
[time complexity wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations)

Now from what I understand Boolean equals is just multiplication of bit-wise and operations, so that would make it less efficient in general.

I have run this python code locally that confirms it:

```
from time import time
a = time()

for i in range(1000000):
    26 == 25
print(time() - a)
## 0.040122032165527344
a = time()

for i in range(1000000):
    26 + 25
print(time() - a)
## 0.031081438064575195
```

**UPDATE** slightly changed code above to make the Boolean equals more efficient

Comment: You'd have to do a test on a specific machine to know for sure. Unless you are doing critical kernel code the difference is likely to be so small that you'd never notice it.

Comment: If you're trying to tease out CPU-level differences, trying to get there through a Python interpreter is trying to use a ruler to measure micrometers. It's simply not an instrument that has the kind of precision you want, and the amount of noise you get (from garbage collection, OS interrupts, etc etc) trying to "blow things up" to the scale you want to measure will overwhelm the signal.

Answer (score 2):

Practically speaking, comparisons are typically implemented in hardware so the cost would be the same as an arithmetic operation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_comparator